# Unexpected value returned by DateTime::diff when querying Twitch API

Tags: php

I have a script that should tell me for how long a certain stream on twitch has been live. The script works, but I get incorrect output. Maybe I made some mistakes with the time formats?

The `created_at` value I get looks like `2016-08-13T16:05:30Z`,
so if I calculate the difference to today (`$heute`) I should get around 0 days, 6 hours, 13 Minutes but the output I receive is 12 Tage (Days), 21 Stunden (Hours), 13 Minuten (Minutes).

For example I used this JSON: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/lirik by setting `$_GET['channel']` to `lirik`.

Here is my current code:

```
$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" . $_GET['channel'];

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

  $creationdate = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($result["created_at"])));
  $heute = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
  $diff = $creationdate->diff($heute);


  if($diff->d > 0) {
    $f = '%d Tage, %H Stunden, %i Minuten';
} elseif($diff->H > 0) {
    $f = '%H Stunden, %i Minuten';
} else {
    $f = '%i Minuten';
}

echo $diff->format($f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$result["created_at"]` isn't set, `strtotime` returns the UNIX Epoch (`1970-01-01 00:00:00`).

It is currently 46 years, 7 months, **12 days, 21 hours, 21 minutes** since midnight on 1 January 1970.

This is because the API doesn't return a `created_at` element at the root of the array, it's in a `stream` subarray.

This should be obvious if you enable error reporting. You'll get an **Undefined index: created_at** error message. You can then `var_dump($result);` to see what's actually returned.

You have a further error: `DateInterval` doesn't have an `H` property, it's `h`.

```
$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" . $_GET['channel'];;

$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

$creationdate = new DateTime($result["stream"]["created_at"]);
$heute = new DateTime();
$diff = $creationdate->diff($heute);

if($diff->d > 0) {
    $f = '%d Tage, %H Stunden, %i Minuten';
} elseif($diff->h > 0) {
    $f = '%H Stunden, %i Minuten';
} else {
    $f = '%i Minuten';
}

echo $diff->format($f);
```

Comment: Thanks, was able to pinpoint those 2 mistakes i made but somehow i still got a wrong date. with your code it seem to work now - finally. now i just need to make a if case when the created_at is null or not avaiable so i can output "Steam not online". any ideas for that matter?

Comment: You can do `if (!isset($result["stream"]) || !isset($result["stream"]["created_at"]))`.